# how to disable elevatedbutton based on the api response in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and can someone tell me how to enable/disable elevatedbutton based on the API response. I need to know for my project. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you follow this rule

```
If onPressed and onLongPress callbacks are null, then the button will be disabled.
```

ohk new answer is here

suppose your response varibale name is Map<dynamic,dynamic> temp so code is below

```
Column(
children:[
.
.
.
ElevatedButton(
onPressed:temp['result']=='OUT'?null:(){
//implement your code
},
child:Text("IN")
)
.
.
.
ElevatedButton(
onPressed:temp['result']=='IN'?null:(){
//Implement your code
},
child:Text("OUT")
)

]


)
```

Comment: as per your question i need api response also for set up logic in elevatedbutton

Comment: the response is parse from json. if the response return 'OUT' the IN button should be disable. If the response return 'IN' the button OUT should be disable. how do I do that

Comment: answer has been edited please review it

Comment: I remove the ['result'] and it worked. thank you so much for this :)

Answer (score 0):

If the result (condition) of the API response is true, it is activated, if it is false, it is deactivated.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: yourApiResponsResult ? (){ implement your code } : null,
  child: Text('ElevatedButton'),
),
```

Comment: the response is parse from json. if the response return 'OUT' the IN button should be disable. If the response return 'IN' the button OUT should be diable. how do I do that?